# NextJS default routing but with namespace

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-routing

I'm developing a site that has 2 variations.

Current setup just re-routes but I don't want the site version to show up in the URL.

```
url: localhost/site1/dashboard
path: /pages/site1/dashboard

url: localhost/site2/dashboard
path: /pages/site2/dashboard
```

The two versions are very similar so they share a component in common. I wanted the user to select from a menu and it changes an internal config that then refreshes without changing the URL.

How I can remove site1/site2 from the URL?

Is there a way to specify to next js some namespace that I can specify in_app.js at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it at runtime. Next.js supports rewrites but it's configured in `next.config.js`. Can't dynamically, based on user input, overwrite Next.js server configuration.

If pages are the same you could unite two versions into one. You can save user selection and just show different components / content / styles based on the user preference.

As alternative, you could show different versions on different subdomains.

Otherwise, you'd have to write your own server to handle this kind of routing.